# Java equivalent of the C++ multimap

Tags: java, c++, dictionary

I am in need of a container that can handle duplicate keys like the C++ `multimap`. Although there exists a known implementation in Guava, I'd like something from the standard Java API. Thanks in advance

Comment: There is no "smooth" implementation similar to C++; I use a tree map or a hash map of lists.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can simulate multimap with just `Map` and `List`: [Java documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/map.html).

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [`Multimap`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html) implementation from [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) library.